# Interview Q: Given m station and n house, output nearest k stations for each house

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There are m stations and n houses, (x,y) coordinates of each station and house are given, output nearest station for each house.

Later, the question was generalised to finding k nearest stations from each house.

My take:
for every house, build a heap of distances(bottom up) to stations and then pop k.
Do the same for all houses.
O(n*(m+klogm));

Alternatively,for every house, build an order statistic tree to stations and then look for node wih rank and traverse the entire tree below that node.
Do the same for all houses.
O(n*(mlogm+logm+k))

Are there any better alternatives to this? Any graph DS based solution, which is better than this?

Comment: Is "build a[n] order statistic tree" an **alternate** solution to the problem? If so, can you indicate so clearly in the question? If it's instead **part of** the solution, why not just look for all stations with a shorter distance than the kth-nearest station found using the heap?

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like an excellent spot to use a [k-d tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), or other space partitioning tree. The problem of "find the k objects nearest some test point" is called the *k-nearest-neighbors problem* and these two data structures solve it remarkably efficiently. They're also reasonably simple to implement.

Specifically: build a k-d tree or quadtree out of the stations. Then, for each house, do a k-nearest-neighbors query on that house in the data structure to find the nearest stations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please add a small description of quad-tree and why it is useful for a 2D search

Comment: @arunmoezhi I don't think I could give a short description here without effectively repeating how to do a k-NN search in a quadtree. That information can probably be found with a quick Google search.

Comment: That was just an opinion so that your answer would look complete

Comment: I'm not too familiar with quad trees, but a brief description of k-d trees and how to find the (k) nearest neighbour(s) using that shouldn't be particularly long, and would help to make this answer a lot more self-contained. [Related Meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212919/is-mentioning-a-well-known-data-structure-or-algorithm-considered-a-link-only-an).

Comment: @Dukeling I'm actually not sure I agree with the meta answer - I once gave out programming k-d trees as a programming assignment in a class I was teaching and it took about 12 or so pages, with diagrams, to fully describe how k-d trees work, what the intuition is, and how the k-NN algorithm works. I honestly don't think I could summarize this here, and any information I did give that described how the k-d trees or quadtrees worked would not be sufficient to explain the k-NN algorithm on them.

Comment: It doesn't have to be sufficient details to implement it yourself, just the basic idea (e.g. "Informal description" and the bullets from "Nearest neighbour search" from Wikipedia - point 3 can probably be reduced to a sentence or two, and slightly extended for k nearest neighbours, and perhaps the 3 images) - although whether you choose to do this is certainly up to you.